# JQuery UI Sortable + DataTables show all rows without refreshing current page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a jquery ui sortable datatable and I'm trying to show all rows on sortable start. I am showing all rows by using `dataTable.page.len(-1).draw(false)` and then `$(this).sortable('refresh')` to allow the newly shown rows to be sortable.

This is working fine, however the refresh of the rows causes the placeholder to be removed, but somehow not the helper.

How can I add all hidden rows to the current page without refreshing the current rows?

I'm not sure if my idea is correct, but I just need the placeholder to stay.

It's a bit difficult to replicate, you need to barely move your mouse on sort start (the placeholder will appear after the `sort` callback is fired), but I am also going to add a table with one record, so that you can see the placeholder does not exist.

#### Example:

```js
$('table').each(function() {
  var table = $(this);
  var dataTable = $(this).DataTable({
    "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
    stateSave: true,
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]]
  });
  var thead = table.find('thead');
  var tbody = table.find('tbody');
  var dataTable = table.DataTable();
  var page_length = null;
  tbody.sortable({
    items: 'tr',
    axis: 'y',
    handle: '.handle',
    placeholder: 'ui-sortable-placeholder',
    start: function(event, ui) {
      ui.item.addClass('ui-sortable-item');

      ui.placeholder.height($(ui.item).height());
      ui.placeholder.width($(ui.item).width());

      // show all rows
      dataTable.page.len(-1).draw(false);

      // refresh so that newly shown rows are counted as sortable items
      $(this).sortable('refresh');

      // sort table by sequence
      dataTable.order([1, 'asc']).draw(false);
    },
    sort: function(event, ui) {
    },
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  background: #eee !important;
  border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
}

.handle {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>handle</th>
      <th>Sequence</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="handle"></div></td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="handle"></div></td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>handle</th>
      <th>Sequence</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="handle"></div></td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Here is what I have tried:**

I tried cloning the placeholder and appending the clone at the end of the start callback (after the refresh) but sortable doesn't recognize the clone as the actual placeholder.

I tried running the datatable functions, such as `dataTable.page.len(-1).draw(false)`, inside of a `.on('sortstart')` because that runs before the actual callback. I don't quite understand why that happens so if someone could explain that as well I would appreciate it.

Comment: Why not use the feature in DataTables: https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/

Comment: @Twisty I didn't know that existed. Do you know if there is a "start" callback for this extension? I still want to show all rows when the user begins dragging a row. Thanks though!

Comment: There is a `row-reorder` event you can listen for: https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/events.html Would be similar.

Comment: There is also a `pre-row-reorder`: https://datatables.net/reference/event/#rowreorder

Comment: @Twisty I found those, it wasn't working for me at first because I was binding the event on document rather than the table. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using Row ReOrder feature in DataTables:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pmyw6do2/

**JavaScript**

```
$('table').each(function() {
  var table = $(this);
  var dataTable = $(this).DataTable({
    "aaSorting": [
      [1, "asc"]
    ],
    stateSave: true,
    "lengthMenu": [
      [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
      [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
    ],
    rowReorder: true
  });
  var thead = table.find('thead');
  var tbody = table.find('tbody');
  var dataTable = table.DataTable();
  var page_length = null;
});
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-sortable-placeholder, .dt-rowReorder-moving {
  background: #eee !important;
  border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
}

.handle {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>handle</th>
      <th>Sequence</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="handle"></div>
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="handle"></div>
      </td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>handle</th>
      <th>Sequence</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="handle"></div>
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See More: https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/